# Why won't the .apk still not install?

Tags: cordova, apk

I've built a Web Application for playing around with Cordova. I added the platforms "ios" and "android". Both work fine in their emulators.

But the .apk I created won't install on the android tablet. Due to the .apk is unsigned after building it with Cordova I signed it manually with the jarsigner.

BTW: The .apk was saved into the "ant-build" folder of the android platform folder. While goolgeing for a solution I often read that the .apk should get created into the "bin" folder. Maybe this is a problem too?

Update: It seems like my Web Application is not the problem. I built the .apk via the cloud services from PhoneGap and it runs fine on the android devices.

Comment: you are correct...apk should be inside the bin folder

Comment: Any ideas how to get it built into there? I created the .apk with "cordova build --release". Then the file was in the "ant-build" folder.